# Jekyll Github pages vs Local server Liquid tags interpretation differences

Tags: jekyll, liquid, github-pages

I use the following liquid tags logic in a html file.

```
{% assign custom_share = true %}

{% for p in site.pages_list %}{% if page.url == p[1] %}
  {% assign custom_share = false %}
{% endif %}{% endfor %}

{% if custom_share %}
    This page is not in the list.
{% endif %}
```

And my jekyll `_config.yml` has a variable `pages_list` something like this

```
pages_list:       
  About: '/about'
  Archive: '/archive'
  Feed: '/atom.xml'
  Email: '/subscribe-via-email'
```

While these liquid tags work properly when I do `jekyll serve` it doesn't seem to work on github pages. Anybody knows why?

Answer (score 1):

Accessing your page list can be done with `site.pages_list`, not `site.github.pages_list` variable.

`site.github` contains metadatas available on [github pages](https://help.github.com/articles/repository-metadata-on-github-pages/) only. 
Note that those metadatas can be accessed locally with the help of [github-metadata gem](https://github.com/jekyll/github-metadata).

Another reason can be that your using [extensionless url](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/permalinks/#extensionless-permalinks) that are not supported for pages by current version of jekyll on Github pages ([see dependencies version here](https://pages.github.com/versions/))

Comment: Thanks. That was a typo in my code, let me edit the question, I actually figure that it was not `site.github.pages_list` and inspite of using `site.pages_list` I got this error. The second part of your answer is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with how Github Pages treated the links.

`page.url` produces values like `/about` or `/archive` locally, but on Github Pages it produces values like `/about.html` or `/archive.html`, even though the browser shows a link such as `{{site.url}}/about` and not `{{site.url}}/about.html`.

Fixed using filters. something like this:

```
{% assign custom_share = true %}

{% assign link = page.url | remove: ".html" %}

{% for p in site.pages_list %}{% if link == p[1] %}
  {% assign custom_share = false %}
{% endif %}{% endfor %}

{% if custom_share %}
    This page is not in the list.
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Also check out the `permalink` setting in your `_config.yml`: http://jekyllrb.com/docs/permalinks/#built-in-permalink-styles